# Full step-by-step instruction for Carthage support

Tags: xcode, dependency-management, carthage

I'm looking for step-by-step tutorial for implementing Carthage support for own library. As Carthage works differently from Cocoapods, I have some questions about integration.
As I get the steps are next:

1. Create Xcode project with name of your lib in root directory of your repo.
2. Include all source files(without example files) into your project.
3. Share Xcode scheme.

Are these complete steps or there are some hidden issues?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing fancy you really have to do to support Carthage, just [share your Xcode schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeShare.html) as illustrated in the Apple Doc.

If you project builds with the following command, it'll definitely build with Carthage too:
`xcodebuild -scheme SCHEME -project PROJECT build`

For a Workspaces:
`xcodebuild -scheme SCHEME -workspace WORKSPACE build`

Now put your library in a `Cartfile` and try it out with carthage:
`carthage build --no-skip-current`

Let me know if you still encounter difficulties.

Comment: It's not quite *that* simple. You have to have a Framework target, for a start, and if the code is Objective-C, you have to `#import` the header files you want to be exposed to users of your framework in the special framework header (which Xcode creates for you when you create a new framework target). You also have to mark those headers as 'public' so they are included in the framework. Also, you can test your build with `carthage build --no-skip-current` without having a `Cartfile`.

Comment: And if I have external dependency like Facebook POP. How should I declare that?